# Как убрать ограничение на загрузку больших файлов на сервер ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня загружаются на сервер только маленькие файлы.
Где можно убрать это ограничение?
Я ставил в web.config, но, даже, если ставлю большие цифры- файлы,скажем 100-200 метров на закачиваются.
Делал, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287706/)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Хотя, причина, возможно, в клиенте...
Я не браузером отправляю, а программой с WebClient. Может здесь как-то надо прописать на больший объём?

```
    dynamic dyn = JObject.Parse(Params.Data);
    dynamic dat = new JObject();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(dyn.FullPath.ToString()))
    {
       HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
       var filename = Path.GetFileName(dyn.FullPath.ToString());
       formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "upload", filename);// загрузка
       var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:2613/siteapi/postfile?code="+ dyn.Code.ToString(), formData).Result; //Отправка
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

В ответе по ссылке - ошибка (и об этом сказано в комметариях)

`httpRuntime` и `security` должны лежать в разных секциях - `system.web` и `system.webServer` соответственно:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" 
            maxRequestLength="2147483647"
            executionTimeout="1600" 
            requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

И еще - `maxRequestLength` указывается в килобайтах; `maxAllowedContentLength` и `requestLengthDiskThreshold` - в байтах, так что подгоните под одинаковые значения. `requestLengthDiskThreshold` при этом не обязательно задирать до `maxAllowedContentLength`.

И вообще - стоит выставить лимиты на основе реально необходимых значений, а не просто "все по 2 гига" :)

Comment: ,что-то я поставил "под потолок" цифры, а видео, размером 200 метров не грузится всёравно(( (я с фидлером не оч пока шарю-не знаю,как посмотреть. -Может быть, что это клиент не отдаёт? можно как-то там изменить ограничение?или на клиенте его нет?)

Comment: @RakzinRoman Можно взять и отправить другим клиентом (лучше формой на сайте). Или можно включить на сервере failed request tracing и посмотреть, что именно мешает заливке.